# Partial Views, redirected to another URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

Am trying to build a project using MVC 4 and Razor. Am having trouble understand partial views. I have a list of my domain objects that I iterate through and display it in a list box (each row being clickable). I split this into main view and a partial view which renders the domain object which works fine. Inside my partial view I want to make each item clickable and upon click, I want to create a new partial view displaying details about the domain object.

Here is what I have

My main view looks like this

```
<div class="panely">
    <div class="list-group">
         @{ Html.RenderPartial("DomainObjectsPartial");}
      </div>
 </div>
```

My partial view looks like this

```
<div class="list">
  @foreach (var x in @Model)
  {
     <a href="@Html.Partial("DomainObjectPartial")" class="list-item">
       <em>@x.Name</em>
     </a>
   }
</div>
```

I have a view named DomainObjectPartial, which has nothing but a small div with hello.
When the user clicks on a domain object, I expect the partial view to be rendered within the main view, but instead I get a error saying

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client (<).

And when I look at my URL, the contents of the partial view are contained within it like

```
http://localhost/<div>hello</div>
```

I dont want to be redirected to another URL. I just want the partial view to be displayed below the list. Can anyone explain to me what am i missing or not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you wanted to use AJAX:

```
<div class="list">
    @foreach (var x in Model)
    {
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Items", new { id = x.Id })" class="ajax-link">
            <em>@x.Name</em>
        </a>
   }
</div>
```

and then you will obviously have a controller action which will render this partial:

```
public class ItemsController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        // go get the specific item from your database using the id and pass it to 
        // the partial view
        var viewModel = ...
        return Partialview("DomainObjectPartial", viewModel);
    }
}
```

and the last part is to AJAXify this anchor:

```
$(function() {
    $('.ajax-link').on('click', function() {
        // Send an AJAX call to the server endpoint pointed by the href attribute
        // of the anchor and inject the results of this endpoint execution inside a 
        // DOM element with id="result"
        $('#result').load(this.href);

        // By returning false you are canceling the default action of the 
        // anchor click and prevent the browser to redirect to the url pointed
        // by the href property. This would leave enough time for your AJAX request
        // to execute and return the results.
        return false;
    });
});
```

and you will obviously need a DOM element with id="result" somewhere on your page to harbor the results of the AJAX call:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```